# CSS text-overflow on label

Tags: label, css

For my website I have a checkbox with a label next to it, but if the text in the label is longer than for example 60px, I want to cut off the text.

I know about the `text-overflow: clip`, this does exactly what I want, but for some reason it doesn't work on a label. And using a div instead isn't a really good solution, since you can't click on the text to select the checkbox then.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

label or span are inline by default. You cannot set width on inline elements.
So make label inline-block

/// markup

```
<input type="checkbox"/> <label style="display: inline-block; width: 60px; overflow: hidden">Sample text sample text</label>
```

Comment: Add `text-overflow: clip` to it, so the `...` appears at the cut-off.

Comment: Yep. missed it. Thanx LinkinTED :)

Comment: For me it is text-overflow: ellipsis that causes the ... to appear (in chrome)

Answer (score 8):

`vertical-align: middle` serves as a great solution here to align the label with the check-box and `text-overflow: ellipsis` for snipping the text with the three dots `...` at the end.

The following snippet shows an example:

```
HTML:   
<input type="checkbox"/> 
    <label>Pretty awesome label to describe the uber cool checkbox. </label>

CSS:
    label {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 300px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Here is a fiddle for you - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ShellZero/rcgsmect/34/)

Answer (score 3):

A utility class `ellipsis` could be used here:

```css
.ellipsis {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```